# Find one key and value form whole mongodb object

Tags: mongodb

I have records in mongodb as below

```
{
    "_id" : "aqDHbgueSaXFWRzys",
    "i18n" : {
        "fa" : {
            "testimonial" : {
                "content" : {
                    "1" : {
                        "testimonialTitle" : {
                            "newValue" : "11111111",                            
                            "isVerified" : false                            
                        },
                        "testimonialDescription" : {
                            "newValue" : "11111111",
                            "isVerified" : false

                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "companyInfo" : {
                "companyName" : "red Fr"
            }
        },
        "tr" : {
            "companyInfo" : {
                "companyName" : "JD Company tr"
            }
        },
        "ar" : {
            "companyInfo" : {
                "companyName" : "ER JD Company"
            }
        },
        "ru" : {
            "companyInfo" : {
                "companyName" : "JD Company Rs"
            }
        }
    },
    "updateDate" : ISODate("2016-08-08T09:34:26.824Z"),
    "testimonial" : {
        "content" : {
            "0" : {
                "testimonialTitle" : {
                    "newValue" : "Testimonial Title 45465 1",
                    "isVerified" : true

                },
                "testimonialDescription" : {
                    "newValue" : "Testimonial Text gfh dfghdfgh 1",
                    "isVerified" : true
                }
            },
            "1" : {
                "described" : {
                    "newValue" : "2",
                    "isVerified" : true

                },
                "communication" : {
                    "newValue" : "2",
                    "isVerified" : true
                },
                "shipingTime" : {
                    "newValue" : "3",
                    "isVerified" : true
                },
                "shipingHandling" : {
                    "newValue" : "3",
                    "isVerified" : true
                },
                "testimonialImageUrl" : {
                    "newValue" : "",
                    "isVerified" : true
                },
                "testimonialTitle" : {
                    "newValue" : "jayeshjayeshjayesh",
                    "isVerified" : true,
                },
                "testimonialDescription" : {
                    "newValue" : "jayeshjayeshjayeshjayeshjayeshjayesh",
                    "isVerified" : true
                },
                "testimonialDate" : {
                    "newValue" : ISODate("2016-08-24T18:30:00.000Z"),
                    "isVerified" : true
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "companyInfo" : {
        "companyName" : "Shanghai GEG Garment Co.,Ltd"
    },
    "storeName" : "sunny1"
}
```

In above object you can find `isVerified` many times. So I want to find that If any `isVerified:true` is remaining or not

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, I tried $elemMatch but it's use only for array. 

my query as below:

db.getCollection('ws_modifystore').find({"homePage.homeTitle":{ $elemMatch:{"isVerified":"false"}}})